# python sql insert statement inserting values with quotes in database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

I am trying to insert data into Mysql in python using the below statements

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO batch_details (batch_id,plant_id,product_code) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s")', (id, plantcode, pcode))
```

Here id ="75", plantcode="2", pcode="FG"

But my values in database are inserted with single quote in mysql database i.e '75','2','FG'

I do not why the values are inserted with single quotes. The syntax of sql query seems to be right.

Comment: Did you try `... VALUES (%s, %s, %s) ...`?

Comment: @Matthias Yes I tried ,I am getting the right output now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

%s means the value you're providing is to be interpreted as a string. For the ones you want to be integers, try using %d instead. You might also need to get rid of the quote characters around the %d parts in your VALUES list if you want SQL to interpret the value as a number and not a string.

Also, when different programs or libraries print a string, some will print it with single-quote characters, some will print it with double-quote characters. Either way it's still a string in your database, it's just printed to the screen in a stylistically different way.

Answer (score 1):

Are you making sure you are turning it into a prepared statement first?  See the documentation example [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorprepared.html) -

```
cursor = cnx.cursor(prepared=True)
stmt = "SELECT fullname FROM employees WHERE id = %s" # (1)
cursor.execute(stmt, (5,))
```

Otherwise, if you want to just do straight string manipulation, you should do

```
query = 'INSERT INTO batch_details (batch_id,plant_id,product_code) VALUES ("%s","%s","%s")'%(id, plantcode, pcode)
cursor.execute(query)
```